# Having severe trouble with finding the appropriate join to use

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, join

In Microsoft Access -

I have two tables, we'll call them OneTbl and TwoTbl

I want to do two things:

1. Pull all records from OneTbl AND only the records from TwoTbl where
      TwoTbl.ID exists in OneTbl.ID
2. Pull records from TwoTbl that weren't pulled in the first query

I tried to do a left join for the first, but the data duplicates. This is an issue. The two tables share all of the same fields, they just have different data.

I did a Count of Distinct ID after I completed the initial run. Theoretically, the counts of queries 1 and 2 as I listed above should sum to the same as the count between tables One and Two. That isn't happening.

The following is the query I wrote for number 1 then I just pasted it onto the end of the excel tab which held all records from table 1:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T2.*
FROM T2 INNER JOIN T1 ON T2.[Payee NPI] = T1.[Payee NPI];
```

This is what I wrote for number 2, to get all remaining records from Table 2 that weren't pulled in the first query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T2.*
FROM T2 LEFT JOIN T1 ON T2.[Payee NPI] = T1.[Payee NPI]
WHERE T1.[Payee NPI] IS NULL
```

Comment: You are doing something wrong.  Share the actual queries you wrote along with examples of the raw data and the output.

Comment: I added the SQL to my original post. I can't really provide raw data or output because of the nature of said data. Only three fields - Payee NPI, Name and Address. The two tables have records which overlap on Payee NPI, but not on Name or Address.

Answer (score 1):

EXISTS and NOT EXISTS can be used:

```
SELECT *
FROM OneTbl
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM TwoTbl t2
WHERE EXISTS
  (SELECT 1
   FROM OneTbl t1
   WHERE t1.ID=t2.ID)

SELECT *
FROM TwoTbl t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 1
   FROM OneTbl t1
   WHERE t1.ID=t2.ID)
```

Comment: Okay, awesome. That SQL is much cleaner than what I had written. Thank you very much. However - the issue still exists. There are a total of 2,787 Distinct IDs between OneTbl and TwoTbl. These two queries should produce the same number of Distinct IDs, right? They don't. They produce 28 extra.

Answer (score 0):

> The two tables share all of the same fields, they just have different
>   data.

Then why not perform a `UNION` between them saying

```
select * from OneTbl
union
select * from TwoTbl
```

> Pull all records from OneTbl AND only the records from TwoTbl where
>   TwoTbl.ID exists in OneTbl.ID

`LEFT JOIN` is what you want here

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from OneTbl t1 left join TwoTbl t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID;
```

> Pull records from TwoTbl that weren't pulled in the first query

You can use `LEFT JOIN` again with `WHERE IS NULL`

```
select t2.* from OneTbl t1
left join TwoTbl t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID
where t2.ID is null;
```

Comment: So good news, I guess - Those are the exact queries that I ran originally and I ended with different NPI counts. Could Access be funking with the data somehow?

Comment: The first LEFT JOIN provided me with 180,000 records. Some sort of cartesian product going on.

Answer (score 0):

You would seem to want something like this:

```
select t1.*
from OneTbl as t1
where exists (select 1 from TwoTbl as t2 where t2.id = t1.id);
```

And,

```
select t2.*
from TwoTbl as t2
where not exists (select 1 from OneTbl as t1 where t2.id = t1.id);
```

Comment: Can you explain what the (select 1 from OneTbl as t1) part of the statement does? I'm assuming it's a placeholder for something I'll need to provide

Comment: @Steven . . . Not at all.  The `exists` clause checks if any *rows* are returned.  The contents of the rows are not important so "1" is as good as any other value -- and simpler to type.

Comment: So is the 1 a count? If using WHERE EXISTS, only 1 row needs to exist to return TRUE. Similar theory in WHERE NOT but if 1 returns it returns false. Or is it actual content within that row?

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  `not exists` is just looking at whether or not a row is returned; the value(s) in the `select` are irrelevant.

Comment: Okay, I think I'm starting to understand. I'll need to look at the documentation. So if I replaced 1 with asdjaflasfk it would work the same way?

Comment: @Steven . . . Yes.  Or with `NULL`.  Or with `*`.